# Java built and run successfully in IntelliJ IDEA but failed to compile in Mac terminal

Tags: java, intellij-idea, compiler-errors

I wrote my java code in IntelliJ IDEA and it builds and runs perfectly fine, but when I tried to use javac to compile the code in my Mac terminal, I keep getting below errors:

```
% javac Main.java 
Main.java:34: error: cannot find symbol
com.business.Helper clsHelper = new com.business.Helper();
            ^       
symbol:   class Helper

location: package com.business
```

both my Main and Helper classes are in the same package (com.business), so I dont understand why javac wouldn't be working.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You haven't told us what your file structure looks like, but I suspect you need to put two directories higher, and use `javac com/business/Main.java`

Comment: You also need to make sure that `Helper.java` is compiled before you compile `Main.java`.

Comment: thanks Jon, I have done that, and same issue.

Comment: good point Ole, let me compile Helper.java first and see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed my problem by build an artifacts (that builds a .jar file), and run use this to run the .jar file in my terminal:
java -cp xxxx.jar xxx.xxx.Main where xxx.xxx is the package that has Main (entry point).